# C# Moq VerifySet throws Expression is not a property setter invocation for non-trivial setter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

In C#, Moq VerifySet is throwing `Expression is not a property setter invocation.` when the setter is non-trivial, even when using SetupProperty or SetupSet.

Here is a trivial example.  Notice that the Antlers setter is trivial and the Antlers2 setter is not trivial.:

```
public class Dancer
{

    public Dancer(bool pIsMale)
    {
        IsMale = pIsMale;
    }

    private bool _IsMale;
    public virtual bool IsMale { get { return this._IsMale; } private set { this._IsMale = value; } }

    private bool _Antlers;
    public virtual bool Antlers
    {
        get { return this._Antlers; }
        set
        {
            this._Antlers = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Antlers2
    {
        get { return this._Antlers; }
        set
        {
            // females cannot have antlers
            if (IsMale)
                this._Antlers = value;
            else
                this._Antlers = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the unit tests.  Second set of three (using Antlers2) are otherwise identical to the first set of three (using Antlers). All of the unit tests using Antlers passes the test. All unit tests using Antlers2 throw `Expression is not a property setter invocation.`, even when using SetupProperty where I thought the entirety of the property's implementation is completely ignored and replaced by Moq.

```
public class DancerTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Antlers_NoSetup()
    {
        // Arrange

        // create mock of class under test
        var sut = new Mock<Dancer>(true) { CallBase = true };

        // Act
        sut.Object.Antlers = true;

        // Assert
        sut.VerifySet(x => x.Antlers = true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Antlers_SetupProperty()
    {
        // Arrange

        // create mock of class under test
        var sut = new Mock<Dancer>(true) { CallBase = true };
        sut.SetupProperty(x => x.Antlers, false);

        // Act
        sut.Object.Antlers = true;

        // Assert
        sut.VerifySet(x => x.Antlers = true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Antlers_SetupSet()
    {
        // Arrange

        // create mock of class under test
        var sut = new Mock<Dancer>(true) { CallBase = true };
        sut.SetupSet(x => x.Antlers = true);

        // Act
        sut.Object.Antlers = true;

        // Assert
        sut.VerifySet(x => x.Antlers = true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Antlers2_NoSetup()
    {
        // Arrange

        // create mock of class under test
        var sut = new Mock<Dancer>(true) { CallBase = true };

        // Act
        sut.Object.Antlers2 = true;

        // Assert
        sut.VerifySet(x => x.Antlers2 = true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Antlers2_SetupProperty()
    {
        // Arrange

        // create mock of class under test
        var sut = new Mock<Dancer>(true) { CallBase = true };
        sut.SetupProperty(x => x.Antlers2, false);

        // Act
        sut.Object.Antlers2 = true;

        // Assert
        sut.VerifySet(x => x.Antlers2 = true);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Antlers2_SetupSet()
    {
        // Arrange

        // create mock of class under test
        var sut = new Mock<Dancer>(true) { CallBase = true };
        sut.SetupSet(x => x.Antlers2 = true);

        // Act
        sut.Object.Antlers2 = true;

        // Assert
        sut.VerifySet(x => x.Antlers2 = true);
    }

}
```

What is it about non-trivial base class property setters that confuse Moq's VerifySet?  I am using Moq 4.7.99, Visual Studio 2015, targeting .Net Framework 4.5.2.

Thanks for the help!  I have benefited greatly from StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you have a confluence of conditions that is creating this weird scenario. It may be a bug worth [reporting](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues), I'm not sure. Anyway, the hitch in your giddy up seems to come from setting `Callbase = true` and/or calling `IsMale` from inside your `Antler2` property setter.

Setting `Callbase = true` creates a `MockInvocation` for every virtual method in your class - including `IsMale` (this will be important later). On the face of it this does not seem like a big deal but it turns out that it is. The exception is being thrown in Moq in the `SetupSetImpl` method. This method verifies that **the last `MockInvocation` called by Moq was a setter** - it does this by checking that the name of the last invocation method starts with 'set_'.

With a normal 'trivial setter' the last invocation would be the setter for `Antlers2` but you have introduced a twist. Inside your setter you are calling `IsMale` and since you also set `Callbase = true` when you created your mock there is a `MockInvocation` for your `IsMale` property. So what happens when you set the `Antler2` property is that 'set_Antler2' gets added to the invocation list and then when `IsMale` is called inside the `Antler2` property setter 'get_IsMale' is added to the invocation list. So when `SetupSetImpl` checks if the last invocation was a setter it instead finds a getter and panics.

I've tested and confirmed that there are at least two ways to prevent this exception. This first is to not set `Callbase = true`. This is a problem, though, because you need the mock object to pass the `Antler2` property setter to the base object - that is the entire point of your test. The other, simpler, solution is to bypass the `IsMale` property altogether and simply call the backing field directly from the `Antler2` property setter like this:

```
if (this._IsMale == true) // Notice I'm calling _IsMale
    this._Antlers2 = value;
else
    this._Antlers2 = false;
```

This works even with `Callbase = true` set because you are not calling the `IsMale` property, and therefore not adding `get_IsMale` to the invocation list. Instead you are simply checking the backing field that the `IsMale` property uses.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation! 
I did, indeed, post this as a bug to GitHub/Moq.  See [here](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/430).

Comment: Something new I noticed.  The execution of the VerifySet causes execution of the property setter.  Even if the property has been mocked with a SetupProperty, the VerifySet executes the actual property setter implementation again.  **Why does VerifySet execute the property setter at all?**  Shouldn't it simply report whether the property setter has already been executed by the test execution?  I believe the re-execution of the actual property setter is the cause of the error, although I still believe you are correct about the 'last invocation method' above, just in a different place.